# Xamarin : Listview change bg color of the item when it is focused using keyboard tab

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

In the xamarin form app we have a listview and when user navigates the listview using keyboard tab/arrow keys the listitem background should change when it has focus.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Bind to the [`IsFocused`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.visualelement.isfocused?view=xamarin-forms#Xamarin_Forms_VisualElement_IsFocused) property of each cell. you can define triggers in a Style or in the DataTemplate so you don't have to manually apply the triggers to each cell:

```cs
<ViewCell>
  <Frame>
    <Frame.Triggers>
      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsFocused, Source={RelativeSource Self}}" TargetType="Frame">
        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Red"/>
      </DataTrigger>
    </Frame.Triggers>
    <Label Text="Sample label"/>
  </Frame>
</ViewCell>
```

Comment: Above approach is not working, the background color is not changing when an item has focus.
@Andrew - is it working for you?

Comment: I can only guess as to what your actual code looks like because you haven't provided any. This is merely an example showing how IsFocused can be data-bound to.